# How to pass data from PageAdapter to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm writing a very simple application in Android, but I have a problem with passing data to a fragment.

I have a TabLayout with ViewPager.

This TabLayout displays two fragements. One fragment is static and hard coded as I intented it to be. Second fragment contains an ImageView, which displays a coupon image.

I'd like my CouponFragemnt to display an image I pass from PagerAdapter to this fragment, but I do not know how to do it.

What to use and how? Bundle, Extras?

I don't have much reputation to post images on StackOverflow, but you can look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm6s4.png

### PageAdapter()

```
class ViewPagerAdapter( fm: FragmentManager, private val numberOfFrags: Int) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return HowToUseFragment()
            1 -> return CouponFragment() // I want to pass data, which tells fragment what image to display.
        }
        return null
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return numberOfFrags
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return "Jak używać?"
            1 -> return "Hamburger"
        }
        return super.getPageTitle(position)
    }
}
```

### CouponFragment()

```
class CouponFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val viewOfLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_coupon, container, false)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            viewOfLayout.coupon_IMGV.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.coupon_hamburger, null))
        }
        else {
            viewOfLayout.coupon_IMGV.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.coupon_hamburger))
        }
        return viewOfLayout
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Bundle way:

```
class CouponFragment:Fragment(){


  ...


companion object {
    const val DATA_KEY= "name"

    fun newInstance(imageId: Int): CouponFragment{
        val fragment = CouponFragment().apply{

       arguments =  Bundle().apply {
            putInt(DATA_KEY, imageId)
        }

     }

        return fragment
    }
}

    ...


 
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val yourAwesomeImage = arguments?.getInt(DATA_KEY)
    // ...
}
```

How to use it:

```
 when (position) {
        0 -> return HowToUseFragment()
        1 -> return CouponFragment.newInstance(R.id.you_awesome_image)

    }
```

Comment: Following Android's newer docs, they reference passing data with fragment navigation xml but that's not applicable in this scenario. This answer was definitely helpful - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use appSession to save data while the app is running. So make an AppSession class to save the image resource.

```
class AppSession {

private var instance: AppSession? = null
@Synchronized
fun getInstance(): AppSession {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = AppSession()
    }
    return instance as AppSession
}

fun setInstance(instance: AppSession) {
    AppSession().instance = instance
}
public var imageUrl:String?=null
//use this to save the image resource as per your code }
```

You can call `AppSession().getInstance().imageUrl` to set image resource in your adapter and then call `AppSession().getInstance().imageUrl` to get the url in your fragment.